# How do you play zombie maps in Call of Duty: World at War over a LAN?

Tags: call-of-duty-world-at-war, cod-world-at-war-zombies

I have a question about Call of Duty World at War.

We are 3 players who want to play in LAN mode, without internet connection to zombies mode.
But it doesn't work... (we have 3 official games patched 1.7).
Do you know if there's a patch or something which allows us to do that ?
Is it possible to sniff the server connection during the game and reproduce it offline ?

Answer (score 4):

[There is a patch which allows you to do this](http://longpoke.blogspot.com/2008/11/call-of-duty-world-at-war-lan-fix.html)... I tried it ages back but it did not work for me, you might have better luck.

Note: It is definitely *not* official, I would check and double check with an antivirus tool and Google the file name to see if anyone else has it working.

Comment: Download links are down.

Answer (score 0):

Look at an application called Tunngle http://www.tunngle.net/en/

this will do exactly what you need.

Comment: Not exactly. OP asked for a patch to play over an **offline** LAN. Tunngle is an **online** network *imitating* an offline LAN. It would only work if every player has an active internet connection.